# Перенос ключа подписи приложений в другой Keystore

Tags: android, google-play, signature, keystore

Есть один Keystore, с несколькими ключами, для подписи приложений(для гугл-плэй).
Возникла необходимость перенести один ключ в другой Keystore(новый).
Можно ли это сделать и как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем просто сделал копию Keystore и удалил оттуда лишнее.
Вот так: keytool -delete -alias Имя -keystore "Путь до keystore"